# SWTBot - check if 3rd party application opened

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp, swtbot

Hi I am writing an SWTBot test which launches a file from a hyperlink using Program.launch. From the bot test I need to check that the 3rd party application opened to display the file. The only thing that seems obvious to me is checking that focus was lost on the underlying workbench but all focus, enabled and visible assertions remain true. Does anyone have any assertion ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to avoid letting the test spawn a process at all. You'll have to wait for the process, kill that process in tear down to leave a clean environment, etc.

If possible I'd rather mock the program launching code during tests and verify that it gets executed if the hyperlink was selected.

But if you really want to test that the 3rd party app was launched , I would rather check if a new process was created. There seems to be neither support in the JRE nor a library to list OS processes so that you probably have to resort to System.exec() `ps` or `tasklist.exe`, depending on the OS you are running on.